# How to use application variables in UnitTest asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have a method that uses Application variables to get information from an external file. Since Application variables are not used in unit tests, is there a way I can get the Application variables values from my Global.asax file and be able to use them in the test?

This is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetCompanyList()
{
    var accController = new AccSerController();
    CInt cInt = new CInt();
    cIn.Iss = "Other";
    cIn.Tick = "BK";
    var result
      = accController.Clist(cIn) as IEnumerable<CList>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023517/unit-test-controller-that-uses-application-scoped-variables  or http://haacked.com/archive/2005/06/11/simulating_httpcontext.aspx/

Comment: i seen the first link, but couldnt really follow along (im new to this). Looking at the second link right now.

Comment: How are you loading the application variable?

Comment: Don't use the application variable for this. Use the repository pattern. Your web pages/controllers shouldn't need to know the details of the repository, just the interface. Then you can use a different implementation of the repository for your unit tests.

Comment: @mason What is a repository pattern? that is the first time i am hearing about that. Where can i learn more about it.

Comment: @User456789 Well, you have Internet access, so that's a great place to start. But I'll post an answer in a little while that will provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). Your controller shouldn't have any idea about `WebConfiguration`.

```
//This defines the stuff that your controller needs (that your repository should contain)
public interface ISiteConfiguration
{
    string Setting1 {get; set;}
}

//Use this in your site. Pull configuration from external file
public class WebConfiguration : ISiteConfiguration
{
    public string Setting1 {get; set;}

    public WebConfiguration()
    {
        //Read info from external file here and store in Setting1
        Setting1 = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/config.txt"));
    }
}

//Use this in your unit tests. Manually specify Setting1 as part of "Arrange" step in unit test. You can then use this to test the controller.
public class TestConfiguration : ISiteConfiguration
{
    public string Setting1 {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) to perform dependency injection, but there's lots of other libraries out there. I'm going to omit some basic Ninject setup from my answer, because there's [plenty of resources](http://aspnetguru.com/how-to-use-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-api-2/) out there. But the below code shows how you'd specify in your web application to use `WebConfiguration` to fulfill the needs of an `ISiteConfiguration`.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)  
{
    kernel.Bind<ISiteConfiguration>().To<WebConfiguration>();
}
```

Here's where the magic happens. When an instance of your controller is created in your web application, Ninject will look at the constructor and see that it's asking for `ISiteConfiguration`. And in your Ninject configuration, you told it to use `WebConfiguration` when it needs `ISiteConfiguration`. So Ninject will create a new instance of `WebConfiguration` and provide (inject) it to your controller.

```
public class AccountServiceController
{
    ISiteConfiguration Config {get; set;}

    //This is called constructor injection
    public AccountServiceController(ISiteConfiguration config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Now you can use Config without needing to know about ISiteConfiguration's implementation details
        //Get settings from Config instead of Application
    } 
}
```

You can also use Ninject in unit testing, but here's a simpler demo where we're not using it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetCompanyList()
{
    //Arrange
    var config = new TestConfiguration(){ Setting1 = "mysetting" };
    var accountController = new AccountServiceController(config);
}
```

The result of all this is that you can use your controller's action methods easily for unit testing, because you can use whatever implementation of `ISiteConfiguration` you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following on some of my tests.  Not ideal but it gets the job done.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
     //   Fill your application variable
}
else
{
     //   Get your data from somewhere else                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of unit testing such scenarios as far as I know.

First one is based on splitting controller function into two: one is  controller function itself, another one implements the logic (e.g.: this is the one you test). Example:

Before:

```
public void MyControllerFunction()
{
    var x = Context["variable"];
    do-something-with-x;
}
```

After:

```
public void MyControllerFunction()
{
    var x = Context["variable"];
    MyControllerLogic(x);
}

internal void MyControllerLogic(object x)
{
    do-something-with-x;
}
```

And then you test `MyControllerLogic()` function instead of `MyControllerFunction()` in unit test

Another methodology is create a surrogate context before invoking unit test.

Example:

```
var controller = new MyController();
controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
controller.Request.Content = new StringContent("{ x: 21 }",
     Encoding.Unicode);
controller.Request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType =
     "application/json";
```

Please note, I did not create HttpContext in 2nd example, I'm not sure if it's a requirement to have. You probably should be able to create it in similar way as well as the other variables you use. It's sort of a hack anyway, so treat it as such