# Unit testing application variables in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Hi I am having trouble unit testing my application that use application variables. Below is my test method. `accController.Clist(cIn)` calls methods that use application variables that are read in from the global.asax file. How and where do I declare it so that the application variables are actually used.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetCompanyList()
{
    var accController = new AccSerController();
    CInt cInt = new CInt();
    cIn.Iss = "Other";
    cIn.Tick = "BK";
    var result = accController.GetClist(cIn) as IEnumerable<CList>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I know that mocking is used, but I am not that experienced with mocking. Also I did not write the code (controllers, models, etc), so i cannot change the layout of it.

Btw I do not have any interfaces, abstract classes, or virtual methods, most other examples are working with one of those.

Comment: I think you need to use mocking for it. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023517/unit-test-controller-that-uses-application-scoped-variables

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using the [AmbientContext pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx)

This basically acts as a mockable wrapper around variables that are static or otherwise difficult to access

It will allow you to keep your application variables declared in the global.asax, but to overwrite them at test time