# How to unit test controller with Response.StatusCode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method on MVC5 controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(TaskViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var task = model.ToTask();
        _taskService.Save(task);
        return Json(task);
    }

    return Json(new ErrorViewModel(ModelState));
}
```

Which I am happily unit testing like so:-

```
[Test]
public void Save_WhenInvalidModel_ThenDoNotCallITaskServiceSave()
{
    var model = new TaskViewModel();
    var service = new Mock<ITaskService>();
    service.Setup(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<Task>()));

    var controller = CreateController(service.Object);

    ValidateModel(model, controller);

    controller.Save(model);

    service.Verify(f => f.Save(It.IsAny<Task>()), Times.Never());
}

protected static void ValidateModel(object model, Controller controller)
{
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults);

    foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
    {
        controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

However, I need to make this method return a 400 status code and return content. So I made the following change to the controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(TaskViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var task = model.ToTask();
        _taskService.Save(task);
        return Json(task);
    }

    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    return Json(new ErrorViewModel(ModelState));
}
```

This causes my unit test to fail with a `System.NullReferenceException` because Response does not exist.

So my question is what is the best practice here to both make this controller testable and also to verify the status code value?

**UPDATE**
While this is very similar to [MVC3 unit testing response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871700/mvc3-unit-testing-response-code) it does not address that I am trying to return JSON content as well as a 400 status code

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 unit testing response code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871700/mvc3-unit-testing-response-code)

Comment: I have already read that question. While that is very close. I want to return a JSONResult as well as a 400 response code. So it is actually pretty different

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871881/47093). It explains in detail how to test using HttpContext and Response.

Comment: Please use the flag as duplicate option instead of posting a link to another question as an answer.

Comment: @cadrell0 how does just flagging it as duplicate help me get an answer though?

Comment: @baynezy It points you to the other question that has an answer.  If your question is not a true duplicate of the one suggested, then explain why it is different, which you have already done.