# Mocking HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, moq

need your help in mocking `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject()` so i can unit test my helper class . I could mock the `HttpContextBase` but for some reason when debugging the unit test the 
`HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject()` is always null ( noticed `HttpContext.Current` is null ). How do i fix this issue ?

Here is my static `HelperClass`

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtentions
{
    public static string GetBrandedCssBundle(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return "BrandTest";
    }

    public static HtmlString Translate(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, string defaultString, string key, params object[] objects)
    {
        var resource = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(null, key);

        if (resource != null)
        {
            defaultString = resource.ToString();
        }

        return objects.Length > 0 ? new HtmlString(string.Format(defaultString, objects)) : new HtmlString(defaultString);
    }

}
```

Here are my unit tests

```
[TestClass]
public class HtmlHelperTest
{

    Mock<HttpContextBase> contextBase {get;private set;};

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initializer()
    {
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);
        user.Setup(ctx => ctx.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
        identity.Setup(id => id.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
        identity.Setup(id => id.Name).Returns("test");
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response.Cache).Returns(CreateCachePolicy());

        contextBase = context;

    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        HttpContext.Current = null;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory(TestCategoryType.UnitTest)]
    public void HtmlHelperExtentions_Translate_WithValidInputs_ReturnsTranslatedContent()
    {
        // Arrange          
        var defaultstring = "TestMessage";
        var inputkey = "XX.Areas.Onboarding.{0}Messages.Message_Onboarding_XX_1001";
        var expectedvalue = "HolaMessage";
        HtmlHelper htmlhelper = null;
        contextBase.Setup(ctx => ctx.GetGlobalResourceObject(null, 
        inputkey)).Returns(expectedvalue);

        //Act
        var result = HtmlHelperExtentions.Translate(htmlhelper, null, inputkey);

        //Assert            
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedvalue, result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if it helps, looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254470/mocking-httpcontext-getglobalresourceobject-in-nunit-with-moq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code above is, although you are setting up `HttpContextBase` its not connected with you code. So when the actual call made in your `Translate` method, the `HttpContext` is not what you mocked hence returning null always.

Since its a standalone class, setting up `HttpContext` is difficult. If this code is been invoked from a controller it would have been possible to write

```
controller.ControllerContext = myMockedContext;
```

To fix this problem, you could work on the lines of solution provide by Mr. Joe in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254470/mocking-httpcontext-getglobalresourceobject-in-nunit-with-moq), you could change your static helper class method something like this, injecting the HttpContextBase object:

```
    public static HtmlString Translate(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, HttpContextBase contextBase, string defaultString, string key, params object[] objects)
    {
        var resource = contextBase.GetGlobalResourceObject(null, key);

        if (resource != null)
        {
            defaultString = resource.ToString();
        }

        return objects.Length > 0 ? new HtmlString(string.Format(defaultString, objects)) : new HtmlString(defaultString);
    }
```

And from your test you could pass mocked contextBase object like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void HtmlHelperExtentions_Translate_WithValidInputs_ReturnsTranslatedContent()
{
    // Arrange          
    var defaultstring = "TestMessage";
    var inputkey = "XX.Areas.Onboarding.{0}Messages.Message_Onboarding_XX_1001";
    var expectedvalue = "HolaMessage";
    HtmlHelper htmlhelper = null;
    contextBase.Setup(ctx => ctx.GetGlobalResourceObject(null, inputkey)).Returns(expectedvalue);

    //Act
    var result = HtmlHelperExtentions.Translate(htmlhelper, contextBase.Object, defaultstring, inputkey);

    //Assert            
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedvalue, result.ToString());
}
```